# What's the area of the shape in the picture

Tags: geometry, area

I came across the following question and suspect insufficient information is provided. If there was no problem with the question, then what should the area of the whole shape be? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[The picture in the question with labeled sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2zR5.png)

From the picture we can see the following:

- $a+a+a=d$
- $b+c=90cm$
- $c=h+g=i+k$
- $d+e+f=140cm$
- $e=10cm$
- $i=70cm$
- $j=20cm$
- $k=5cm$
- $f+j=90cm$

From this, we can conclude, that

$f=90cm-j=70cm$

$d=140cm-e-f=60cm$

$a=\frac d3=20cm$

$c=i+k=75cm$

$b=90cm-c=15cm$

Therefore, the area of this shape is $$Area=a\times b+d\times c+e\times g+f\times (i+k)+j\times k=20cm\times 15cm+60cm\times 75cm+10cm\times g+70cm\times (70cm+5cm)+20cm\times 5cm=10150cm^2+g\times 10cm$$
It seems, that the size of $g$ cannot be deduced as it is only present in equation $c=h+g$, where $h$ is also unknown. The best we can do is to estimate it. From the picture $0<g<e=10cm$. Therefore, the area is
$$10150cm^2<Area<10250cm^2$$

Comment: Thank you, Fullfungo, for your illustration and analysis. It seems at the moment that there is insufficient information provided. This is a question from my daughter's Olympic Math exercise booklet for primary school students. She'll ask her teacher next time they meet in class online, of course, given the current lockdown for COVID-19 in Australia. Let's wait and see what her teacher has to say about how to solve the question. Thank you very much again for your participation.